# Fast_extract with velox archieved in R

Tags: raster, r, extract

I am new to how to manipulate spatial data, so unfortunately after finding the command I want to use which is fast_extract as the following:
rs <- fast_extract(rd, county, velox = TRUE, fun = mean, na.rm = T, small = T, df = T, cellnumbers = F, sp = F)
where rd is a raster layer and county is the shapefile, it says that "velox" has been archieved, what should I do in this case?

Comment: You can try the `exact_extract` function in the exactextractr package or `extract` in the terra package which happens to be the eventual repacement for raster.

Comment: thanks @JeffreyEvans